# ReactJS hooks How to change calendar language on react-dates?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, internationalization, react-dates

### I need to change the calendar language of the react-dates lib to pt-br. But I didn't find anything about it.

`

```
    <S.Container>
      <DateRangePicker
        startDatePlaceholderText="Ida"
        endDatePlaceholderText="Volta"
        showDefaultInputIcon
        orientation={orientation}
        withFullScreenPortal={withFullScreenPortal}
        startDate={startDate}
        startDateId="date-start-date"
        endDate={endDate}
        endDateId="date-end-date"
        onDatesChange={handleDatesChange}
        focusedInput={focusedInput}
        onFocusChange={(focusedInput) => setFocusedInput(focusedInput)}
        numberOfMonths={numberOfMonths}
        displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
        dayAriaLabelFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
        disabled={!isTwoWays && "endDate"}
        autoFocus={false}
      />
    </S.Container>
```

`

[Doc react-dates.github.io](https://react-dates.github.io/react-dates/?path=/story/daterangepicker-drp--default)